# Navigation breaks on hover in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, xhtml

I'm having a slight problem. Whenever I hover over the "SEO" option on my navigation in IE, the navigation breaks & moves to the side. This doesn't happen in Firefox. Changing the navigation to position:absolute fixes it, but then the main content becomes merged with the navigation. It all validates. Any help would be much appreciated!

http://www.joemarketeer.com

http://jsfiddle.net/eoJ1/Ra4tR/

Thanks loads!

Comment: Can you cut your code down to the relevant parts, instead of the whole page? Makes it easier to debug.

Comment: Done :)
http://jsfiddle.net/eoJ1/u35mS/

Comment: Firstly, in Chrome the links on the blue background on your website are not showing the line below on hover. However, they're showing in the jsfiddle example.

Comment: When visiting the site, the nav is all askew in IE8, but pops back into line in IE7...

Comment: @AbhranilDas Sorry, someone gave me advice which made it look odd in all browsers. I've reverted it back and it's working in Chrome now.

@ cale Odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `navleft` and `navright` divs are resizing independently, which is to be expected given your design structure. But it looks weird as it comes down on top of the content below:

[image: Bad content reflow with resize]

One suggestion I can give you is not to set the navigation bar width in %, which you have done for these two divs. If you set a fixed width (in px) or remove the width specification completely (in which case it will take the width of its inner content), a horizontal scrollbar will appear below the page when the width is small, which I suppose is fine.  Also, use as few `float`s as possible as they break the flow of content in the document and are more prone to breaking layouts. Both these divs have a `float:left`, which can be dumped for more stable solutions.  I'm saying all this because I think the breaking of the layout on hover is occurring due to these reasons. If you can take care of this, your problem might disappear.

So my suggestion is to have a single `nav` div with `width: 100%`. Inside this put two divs: `navleft` and `navright` with `display:inline` and widths  a.) specified in px or not at all, or b.) specified in % but with some `min-width` in px. If you don't specify any width for `navright`, it will expand to fill all of the space on the right.

This way these two divs will not reflow independently.

Basically, toy around more until you get better command over CSS; I think more experience will automatically help you sort out issues like this.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I needed a shower.

Hmmm, kk. Do you have any ideas on an alternative to the floats? I gave this a try: http://blog.betabong.com/2009/02/25/css-alternative-to-left-float/ and it didn't help. Thanks! :)

Comment: Actually, I've managed to solve it - I'd been told to avoid margin-top, because IE doesn't like it. It managed to fix it though. It's probably a bit clunky, but it works. Thanks loads for all the help! :)